# How to modify the view to only show the data to one assigned user?

Tags: python, django

**Problem:**
I would like to assign a bank statement for each user. Each user will log in using their username and password, and access their document. At the moment, one user can see the statement of all users.

**Option 1:**
I`ve added a manytomany relationship for the user to the model. When logged in on the Admin interface, I can assign the Bank Statement to the user.

**Question:**
What is the right way to define the views.py or the html file to only show the bank statement to the user logged-in.

**models.py**

```
class BankStatement(models.Model):
    
    user = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='bs')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def bankstatement_detail(request, bankstatement_id):
    bankstatement = BankStatement.objects.get(pk=bankstatement_id)   
    context = {
                'bankstatement': bankstatement,                         
            }            
    return render(request, 'administration/bankstatement_detail.html', context)
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
    def index_bankstatement(request):
        user = request.user
        bankstatement = BankStatement.objects..filter(user=request.user) 
        context = {
                    'bankstatement': bankstatement,                         
                }            
        return render(request, 'administration/bankstatement_detail.html', context)
```

**bankstatement_detail.html**

```
<div class="card-block table-border-style">
   <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
             <tr>
               <th>#</th>
               <th>Name</th>
               <th>Date Created</th>
               <th>Last Updated</th>
              </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
            {% for bankstatement in bankstatements %}
             <tr>
               <td>{{ bankstatement.id }}</td>
               <td>{{ bankstatement.name }}</td>
               <td>{{ bankstatement.date_created }}</td>
               <td>{{ bankstatement.last_updated }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}                              
        </tbody>
     </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Many Thanks

Comment: I think you have to do it in views, not in the models. Check the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/. And google an example on Django authentication.

Comment: Good intro example: https://thecodinginterface.com/blog/django-auth-part1/

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you are still working on this one, but

1. I do not agree with linking of the BankStatement to the User as ManyToMany. In my opinion, one user can have many statements, but one statement has only one user. So it is a one to many relationship defined by Foreign Key.
2. Let's fix the view:

```py
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def bankstatement_detail(request, bankstatement_id):

    # this line forces to show the statement of the logged in user
    user = request.user

    bankstatement = BankStatement.objects.get(pk=bankstatement_id, user=user)   
    context = {'bankstatement': bankstatement,}    
        
    return render(request, 'administration/bankstatement_detail.html', context)
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I was stuck on this issue and did not make any progress. I will update my code. One question, I have added an 'index_bankstatements' to my post. Is it correctly written or do I need to use a 'get()' instead the 'filter()'?  Many Thanks

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to be correct: as far as I understand you need to create two views (a) statement detail view and (b) user statements list. The issue is with your template: you are using one and the same template for the statement detail view and for the statement list view, moreover the template bankstatement_detail.html should actually serve as bankstatemen_list.html.